# Back Button won't go to previous Page Android

Tags: android

I am using this [Mikepenz Material Drawer Library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) for my drawer. When an item is clicked on the Drawer, it moves to a page and from this page, a user can navigate further to another page.

That is:

```
  Drawer Item -> List of Items -> Item Details
```

The problem is when the user click on the Back on the `Item Details` page, it doesn't move back to `List of Items` page. But when a task is done (e.g post comment) on the `Items Details` page, the back button will then move to the previous page correctly.

My code:

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Bean item = Bean.get(arg2);
            dbHelper.insertItemID(String.valueOf(item.getId()));
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, new ItemDetails())
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

The above code is to move to the `Item Details` page.

**Note:**
I am using fragments for both pages.

Comment: please provide your activity/fragment code

Answer (score 0):

*> My piece of advice would be ,*

**1.Upgrade from using a `ListView` to a `RecyclerView`.**

**2. If you want to achieve the back `Button` when your class is extending the `AppCompatActivity` , you can do the following;**

a). Put the following code in the `onCreate` Method.

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("e.g comment..");
```

b). Then put the following code in `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Once handle the popping up of the back stack yourself and check it ..  It worked for me

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                //getActivity().finish();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, new ListOfItems()).commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```